# Return a boolean after a sql query with typescript

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, request

This is my function :

```
static async isExiste (email: string) {
        const bdd = mysql.createConnection({
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASS,
            database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
            socketPath: process.env.SOCKETPATH,
            port: parseInt((process.env.PORTMYSQL === undefined) ? '3306' : process.env.PORTMYSQL)
        })
        const emailExist = `SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE email='${email}'`
        let bool = false
        await bdd.query(emailExist, (err, result) => {
            if(result[0]) {
                bool = true
                console.log(bool)
            } else {
                bool = false
                console.log(bool)
            }
        })
        console.log('boolean renvoyé: ', bool)
        return bool
    }
```

And this is the return of the console :

```
boolean renvoyé:  false
true
```

The return of the function is false when it should be true.
I don't understand why the sql request doesn't block the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bdd.query()` does not return a promise, and your `console.log()` and return statements are outside of the query callback, meaning they occur before the callback is called. You can fix this by returning a promise and then resolving the promise with your return value. Modifying your code to look something like this should work:

```
static isExiste (email: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const bdd = mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      socketPath: process.env.SOCKETPATH,
      port: parseInt((process.env.PORTMYSQL === undefined) ? '3306' : process.env.PORTMYSQL)
    })
    const emailExist = `SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE email='${email}'`
    bdd.query(emailExist, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }

      const bool = !!result[0];
      console.log('boolean renvoyé: ', bool)
      resolve(bool)
    })
  });
}
```